# How to make code focused on adaptability and CMS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Want to make it responsive, and the information on the elements in the first line (1-4) is required to show only under the first row, on the mobile it will be two or one element Information about the elements from the second row (5-8) under the second row In the screenshots I tried to show how I would like to see this

```js
$(".items .item").click(function() { // Клик по айтему
  $(".items .item").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
  $(".hidden-block .item-content").slideUp().eq($(this).index()).slideDown();
});
```

```css
  .items {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.item:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #e6e4e3;
}

.item {
  background: #f2f1f0;
}

.items img {
  filter: grayscale(80%);
  transition: all 0.4s;
  height: 100px;
}

.items img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.items .item {
  padding-top: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
}

.right,
.left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.hidden-block .item-content {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}

.items .item.active {
  background: #00000061;
}

.items .item.active+.hidden-block {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .items .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/html-5.svg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/css-3.svg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/html-5.svg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/css-3.svg"></div>
</div>
<br clear="all" />
<div class="hidden-block">
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/html-5.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h2>HTML 5</h2>
      <span class="href"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5</a></span>
      <p>HTML5[a] is a markup language used for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web. It is the fifth and current major version of the HTML standard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/css-3.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h2>HTML 5</h2>
      <span class="href"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5</a></span>
      <p>HTML5[a] is a markup language used for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web. It is the fifth and current major version of the HTML standard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/html-5.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h2>HTML 5</h2>
      <span class="href"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5</a></span>
      <p>HTML5[a] is a markup language used for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web. It is the fifth and current major version of the HTML standard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/css-3.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h2>HTML 5</h2>
      <span class="href"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5</a></span>
      <p>HTML5[a] is a markup language used for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web. It is the fifth and current major version of the HTML standard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br clear="all" />
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/html-5.svg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/css-3.svg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/html-5.svg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/css-3.svg"></div>
</div>
<br clear="all" />
<div class="hidden-block">
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/html-5.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h2>HTML 5</h2>
      <span class="href"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5</a></span>
      <p>HTML5[a] is a markup language used for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web. It is the fifth and current major version of the HTML standard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/css-3.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h2>HTML 5</h2>
      <span class="href"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5</a></span>
      <p>HTML5[a] is a markup language used for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web. It is the fifth and current major version of the HTML standard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/html-5.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h2>HTML 5</h2>
      <span class="href"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5</a></span>
      <p>HTML5[a] is a markup language used for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web. It is the fifth and current major version of the HTML standard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://cdn.svgporn.com/logos/css-3.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h2>HTML 5</h2>
      <span class="href"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5</a></span>
      <p>HTML5[a] is a markup language used for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web. It is the fifth and current major version of the HTML standard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[How must ork first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ3Kk.png)
[How must work second row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQaun.png)

Comment: How have you tried to make this responsive so far?

Comment: I can't understand logic

Comment: Here's a good article that may help: [Logic in Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)